# Zigbee network setup for transmission from E(End module) to C(Coordinator) via R(non polling router)

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I am trying to setup a cluster-tree with 3-4 xbee 865 (S8), with nodes configured as
1 - Coordinator (API mode)
1 - Standard Router (API mode)
1 - Non Routing Module

I want network to setup such that, Communication between the coordinator and the non-routing module always takes via standard router (even if the devices are kept in range.)

1. What steps must be carried out to setup such a network??
2. Should i configure the DH/DL of coordinator to SH/SL of router and DH/DL of router to SH/SL of module  (point-to-point communication) and have a micro-controller at Standard router to process the data received from Coordinator and modify the API frames to route data to non-routing module?? in such a case, the reverse transmission (data from module to coordinator) will not be done without modifying DH/DL of both router and module.
3. Can such a network be setup without micro-controller, using xctu software
   only?? what steps??
4. Should i use zigbee api frames or digimesh api frames??
5. How do i ensure that the data transfer between the coordinator (to and fro) is done via router only??? (as all 3 are in the range, my attempts have resulted to transmission of data between the coordinator and the module directly, bypassing the router).

Note: xbee 865 (S8) doesnt have MYID

Answer (score 1):

xbee 865 (S8) modules run Digimesh protocol, which is a proprietary protocol. The above situation is not achievable using digimesh, as digimesh is a true mesh and nodes in range communicate directly with each other.